# Implementing RFC 2369's "List-Unsubscribe" in PHP website - should I send confirmation?

Tags: php, email, email-spam, rfc

I'm trying to implement RFC 2369's "List-Unsubscribe" in a PHP website which sends out daily updates by email.

I'm planning to use the HTTP option only since this can be implemented simply in PHP code.

My question is this: Once the user is unsubscribed, is it ok to send out a confirmation email, like "unsubscribe successful"? Or will this count against my site's "unsubscribe score" by Google et al?

I've tagged this as PHP because I'm interested strictly in a PHP-programming based answer to the proper implementation of this standard.

Answer (score 1):

If implemented in a website, acknowledge the successful unsubscribe on the result web page.
You will have to evaluate if this is an environment where the possibility of someone getting unsubscribed by another person is an issue or not. If it is, I would send the email message saying that someone unsubscribed you, if that is not what you want follow this link to resubscribe.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, but I'm still interested in finding out whether this final confirmation would affect our "unsubscribe score" ... unfortunately just another secret google metric...